# How to pass parameter to my POWERBI embedded report?

Tags: powerbi

I have an IFrame which shows a PowerBI embedded Report that shows a list of Accounts.

I want to pass in an Account ID so that I only see the sales for my Account.

In side the report I have a Table lets say in called Query1 and Inside that table I have a field called AccountID.  I need to add to my URL to filter the Accountid = 123.

My URL is something like this....
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxxxxxxxxxxx&autoAuth=true&ctid=xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXdlc3QtZXVyb3BlLXJlZGlyZWN0LmFuYWx5c2lzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LyJ9

What exactly should I add to filter the report by the AccountID?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for Row Level Security feature of PowerBI.

Answer (score 1):

You should add url parameter called filter. You need to specify table and field you want to filter and add value of the filter after eq. So your end result should be something like that:

```
URL?filter=Table/Accountid eq 123.
```

Here's Microsoft documentation about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#query-string-parameter-syntax-for-filtering

**Update** top part of course works for filtering reports in the appor work space itself. To filter embedded report you need to specify the page and filter in a similar fashion for the embedded link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure. So you link will be something like that:

```
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?blabla&pageName=Page1&$filter=Table/Accountid eq 123
```

Here how it would like once embedded:
[image: result with embedded report]

Comment: This may seem very stupid but I am new to POWERBI.   When you put Table is that equal to my Query or is it static?

Comment: I've created the following and it still does not filter my report.   https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxxxxxxxxx&autoAuth=true&ctid=yyyyyyyyyy&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXdlc3QtZXVyb3BlLXJlZGlyZWN0LmFuYWx5c2lzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LyJ9&filter=Query/B2BAcc_AccountAK eq 123

Comment: In the link that you sent I don't see eq or in parameter, instead you have underscore&filter=Query/B2BAcc_AccountAK.
It should be &filter=Query/B2BAcc eq AccountAK.
Also make sure column B2BAcc is in the Filter panel in you PBI report

Comment: Michael thank you for trying to help.    Here is the URL I have apparently it did not paste completely  https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxxxxxxxxx&autoAuth=true&ctid=yyyyyyyyyy&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXdlc3QtZXVyb3BlLXJlZGlyZWN0LmFuYWx5c2lzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LyJ9&filter=Query/B2BAcc_AccountAK eq 123              I do have the B2BAcc_AccountAK as a report level parameter.  When the report loads it just will NOT filter.    HELP!

Comment: I totally overlooked you were asking about embedded report,sorry. See updated version of my answer

Comment: @Kd5490 if it worked please accept this answer